# How can I get the constructor from the class I inherit?

Tags: java

I have the constructor on the `FresherCandidate` class which inherits from the `Candidate` class. I want to get the field from the `Candidate` class but I'm stuck.
This is constructor in the Candidate class:

```
public Candidate(String IDCandidate, String Firstname, String Lastname, String Birthdate, String Address, String Phone, String Email, int CandidateType) {
    this.IDCandidate = IDCandidate;
    this.Firstname = Firstname;
    this.Lastname = Lastname;
    this.Birthdate = Birthdate;
    this.Address = Address;
    this.Phone = Phone;
    this.Email = Email;
    this.CandidateType = CandidateType;
}
```

and the constructor in the FresherCandidate class:

```
public FresherCandidate(String GraduationDate, String GradudationRankm, String Education, String IDCandidate, String Firstname, String Lastname, String Birthdate, String Address, String Phone, String Email, int CandidateType) {
    super(IDCandidate, Firstname, Lastname, Birthdate, Address, Phone, Email, CandidateType);
    this.GraduationDate = GraduationDate;
    this.GradudationRankm = GradudationRankm;
    this.Education = Education;
    
}
```

How can I put these code:

```
this.IDCandidate = IDCandidate;
    this.Firstname = Firstname;
    this.Lastname = Lastname;
    this.Birthdate = Birthdate;
    this.Address = Address;
    this.Phone = Phone;
    this.Email = Email;
    this.CandidateType = CandidateType;
```

into the constructor in the FresherCandidate:

```
public FresherCandidate(String GraduationDate, String GradudationRankm, String Education, String IDCandidate, String Firstname, String Lastname, String Birthdate, String Address, String Phone, String Email, int CandidateType) {
    super(IDCandidate, Firstname, Lastname, Birthdate, Address, Phone, Email, CandidateType);
    this.GraduationDate = GraduationDate;
    this.GradudationRankm = GradudationRankm;
    this.Education = Education;
    --> here
}
```

Comment: super is the correct constructor for parent class

Comment: You don't need to do this yourself. When you call `super(IDCandidate,...` these get set for you. Try a print statement inside the constructors to see what happens when.

Comment: But when i print the statement, all variable in constructor at the Candidate class turn to null. I dont know why

Comment: OK. So I think you're asking something else really. Can you show us your code with the prints, then we might be able to tell you why they are null. Your question might be more like "Why are the member variables null when I do the following..."

Comment: Did you declare the variables again in the `FresherCandidate` class?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like your "shadowing" when you extend a class you don't want to declare the variables again.

```
class A{
    String name;
    A(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
}

class B extends A{
    String name;
    String number;
    B(String name, String number){
        super(name);
        this.number = number;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return name + ", " + number + ", " + super.name;
    }
}
```

Since I declared a variable `name` in B, B essentially has two names. The A constructor assigns one of them.

```
System.out.println( new B("bob", "two") );
```

> null, two, bob

The solution is to remove the declaration of `name` in the B class. Or in your case, remove the duplicate variable names in your extended class eg `IDCandidate` should only be declared in Candidate.